# Exclude certain paths from being autoimported with Lerna, Typescript, and VS Code

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, tsconfig, lerna

I have a lerna@3.16 project with a chain of multiple packages.

```
|-tsconfig.lib.json
|-packages
  |--format
  |----tsconfig.lib.json
  |--helper
  |----tsconfig.lib.json
```

Each package extends the tsconfig.lib.json from the top level. `helper` depends on `format`. When I go to auto import from format, I get three levels of imports:

- `packages/helper`
- `@org-name/helper` (the right one)
- `packages/helper/dist`

How do I exclude the two import paths with `packages` without breaking all imports?

Answer (score 1):

Years later, I think that https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/project-references.html are the way to handle this with Typescript, at least.

Each tsconfig within `packages` would have a

```
   // packages/helper/tsconfig.lib.json
   "references": [
        { "path": "../format" }
    ]
```

The root package.json would include

```
"paths": {
   "@org-name/helper": "./packages/helper"
}
```